# Refreshing and the shrinking header

Tags: jquery, css

I've such code for shrinking header (later follows the "else" command, but it's not important). It works perfectly, but when I refresh already scrolled page, I have to scroll again to trigger the change. How to change that and display the proper shrinked version when refreshing with page already scrolled? Thanks in advance for the advice.

```
 var shrinkHeader = 50;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
      if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader || scrollTop() >= shrinkHeader) {
$('.pasek-mini').hide();
 $('.pasek-mini').addClass('pasek-miniu').removeClass('pasek-mini');
$('.pasek-miniu').show();     
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your scroll position comparisons both when the page loads and after you scroll, and do your header shrinking magic.

```
function shrinkHeaderIfScrolled() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    var shrinkHeader = 50;
    if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader || scrollTop() >= shrinkHeader) {
        $('.pasek-mini').hide();
        $('.pasek-mini').addClass('pasek-miniu').removeClass('pasek-mini');
        $('.pasek-miniu').show(); 
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    shrinkHeaderIfScrolled();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        shrinkHeaderIfScrolled();
    }
});
```

This is assuming you have both a `getCurrentScroll()` function and `scrollTop()` function defined somewhere since you included them in your code sample.

Otherwise you could just use:

```
function shrinkHeaderIfScrolled() {
    var shrinkHeader = 50;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= shrinkHeader) {
        $('.pasek-mini').hide();
        $('.pasek-mini').addClass('pasek-miniu').removeClass('pasek-mini');
        $('.pasek-miniu').show(); 
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    shrinkHeaderIfScrolled();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        shrinkHeaderIfScrolled();
    }
});
```